# Details tab not showing record data and new button not working correctly. access issue of object

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-apps, custom-profile

A user is facing the following issue when he clicks on the details section of a custom object tab and for New Button

**Looks like there's a problem.**

**Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details.**

The user has create and edit permissions for the object through the permission set. I checked with the user having the same permission set but a different profile and he is not facing the above issue.

I checked for that profile's apex class access, flow access, and lightning record page access. not able to find the root cause.

Comment: Did you check if Detail section is standard or any custom component?

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala, it is a standard component

Comment: any conditional rendering set up for that component?